# PHP: unset from array using if statement

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I'm trying to unset specific values using if statement.
My code is

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($fruits); $i++){ 
    if ($fruits[$i] == 'apple' || $fruits[$i] == 'orange' || $fruits[$i] == 'melon' || $fruits[$i] == 'banana'){
        unset($fruits[$i]);
    }
 }
 print_r($fruits);
```

I'm expecting it to return

```
Array
(
  [4] => pineapple
)
```

But the result is

```
Array
(
  [3] => banana
  [4] => pineapple
)
```

Why isn't 'banana' unset from the array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many ways to Rome, as they say..

#### Using `foreach()`

A cleaner approach would be to use `foreach` instead of `for` loops, and checking against an array using `in_array()` instead of individually checking all the fruits.

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];

foreach ($fruits as $key=>$fruit) {
    if (in_array($fruit, ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana'])) {
        unset($fruits[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($fruits);
```

#### Using `array_filter()`

A more "fancy" way would be a one-liner using `array_filter()`,

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];

$fruits = array_filter($fruits, function($fruit) {
    return !in_array($fruit, ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana']);
});
print_r($fruits);
```

#### Using `array_diff()`

Even simpler, use `array_diff()`, which finds all elements that exists in only one of the arrays (essentially removing the duplicates).

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];
$remove = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana'];
$result = array_diff($fruits, $remove);
```

#### Using `array_intersect()`

There's also `array_intersect`, which is sort of the inverse of `array_diff()`. This would find elements that exists in both arrays, and return that.

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];
$find = ['pineapple'];
$result = array_intersect($fruits, $find);
```

- [Live demo using `foreach()`](https://3v4l.org/QM1fL)
- [Live demo using `array_filter()`](https://3v4l.org/qnAvL)
- [Live demo using `array_diff()`](https://3v4l.org/TqSn8)
- [Live demo using `array_intersect()`](https://3v4l.org/SEurW)
- [PHP.net on `in_array()`](http://php.net/in-array)
- [PHP.net on `array_diff()`](http://php.net/array-diff)
- [PHP.net on `array_filter()`](http://php.net/array-filter)
- [PHP.net on `array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array-intersect)
- [PHP.net on `foreach()`](http://php.net/control-structures.foreach)

Comment: Kiki, I'm glad you learned something! That's what StackOverflow is all about - sharing knowledge! dWinder, your answer solved the specific issue - and explained why the current code didn't work. I just showed different (and perhaps more efficient) ways to achieve the same thing!

Answer (score 11):

Because after removing the first 3 element the `$i` value is 3 but the count of the array is 2 so the for loop breaks - remember the loop condition is **re-evaluating in each iteration**. Change to this will give you the desire output:

```
$size = count($fruits)
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $size; $i++){
```

Generally, using `unset` with `for` loop with int index is not recommended

Comment: Ah now I get it! Thank you so much!
Should I use `foreach` instead of unset?

Comment: Yes you can @Kiki

Comment: just curious how you get 7 upvotes only by 2 minutes. :)

Comment: Removing elements in a for loop is no problem, but you should reverse the loop, so count from end to 0. `for($i=count($fruits); $i >= 0; $i--) ...`.

Comment: My approach would be having a second array of "badwords" and then check against with `in_array`. That's more readable than an endless if statement.

Comment: @MarkusZeller both your suggestion are good - I only try to show the OP where he mistaken - fill free to add your suggestion to my answer

Comment: @unreleased I also surprised - my highest upvoted post till today :)

Answer (score 4):

I think problem is `$i<count($fruits)`. It reduce the array size. So it's runs only 3 times. SO assign the array size to variable first.

```
<?php 

    $fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];
    $n=count($fruits);
    for ($i = 0 ; $i <$n ; $i++){ 

     if ($fruits[$i] == 'apple' || $fruits[$i] == 'orange' || $fruits[$i] == 'melon' || $fruits[$i] == 'banana'){
         unset($fruits[$i]);
      }
     }
     print_r($fruits);

?>
```

Comment: Code only answer are not very much entertaining. And I suppose dwinder had already proposed the same solution with good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to use `foreach` instead of `for loop`. Try the following code below.

```
<?php
$fruitss = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple','h'];

foreach ($fruitss as $key=>$fruits) {
    //echo $fruits;
    if ($fruits == 'apple' || $fruits == 'orange' || $fruits == 'melon' || $fruits == 'banana') {
        unset($fruitss[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($fruitss);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible ways to do this in PHP as PHP is very rich with array and string functions.

In this answer, two approaches are discussed.

Basically, you want to remove the elements from array.

So, take another array with the elements you want to remove.

Find out the difference between your array and the new array.

Difference will definitely your expected result.

You can use `array_diff()`

Beauty of this approach is:

You can do it minimal lines of code, also, no loops required.

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];
$remove = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana'];
$test = array_diff($fruits, $remove);
echo '<pre>';print_r($test);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [4] => pineapple
)
```

Or even using `array_interset()`

Take a temporary array with the only element(s) you want to maintain in your array.

Get array intersecting element.

You will have all other elements removed.

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];
$two = ['pineapple'];
$test2 = array_intersect($fruits, $two);
echo '<pre>';print_r($test2);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [4] => pineapple
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here count($fruits), because every loop cycle array going small.

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];
$count = count($fruits);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){ 
    if ($fruits[$i] == 'apple' || $fruits[$i] == 'orange' || $fruits[$i] == 'melon' || $fruits[$i] == 'banana'){
        unset($fruits[$i]);
    }
}
print_r($fruits);
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

use This:

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];

$fruit_num = count($fruits);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $fruit_num; $i++){

    if ($fruits[$i] == 'apple' || $fruits[$i] == 'orange' || $fruits[$i] == 'melon' || $fruits[$i] == 'banana'){
        unset($fruits[$i]);
    }

}
print_r($fruits);
```

instead of :

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($fruits); $i++){ 
  if ($fruits[$i] == 'apple' || $fruits[$i] == 'orange' || $fruits[$i] == 'melon' || $fruits[$i] == 'banana'){
    unset($fruits[$i]);
  }
}
print_r($fruits);
```

Output :

```
Array ( [4] => pineapple )
```